# no visible @interface for 'NSURLConnection' declares the selector 'start' when release mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, release-mode

I'm using MKNetworkKit in my project. 
In MKNetworkOperation.h file:

```
@interface MKNetworkOperation (/*Private Methods*/)
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;
...
```

In .m file, - (void)start method:

```
...
[self.connection start];
...
```

Here's the strange thing. When I build or run the app in debug mode, it works fine. But when I set the build configuration to release, it fails to compile and says `no visible @interface for 'NSURLConnection' declares the selector 'start'`.

[image: screen]
I'm using XCode 6.1.

I tried to reinstall XCode, but problem still exists.

My other projects don't have this problem.

I tried to build the same code on another Mac, it SUCCESSED!

Does anyone knows where I was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you edited header files of system framework.

To make sure that your `NSURLConnection.h` is still original, you should CMD+CLICK to jump into it.

[image]

If you don't see `start` method, you should download a new xcode installer and install it again

**===== UPDATE ======**

Really really not understand why it happened. You should try to download a new xcode, delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, reboot your mac.

Hope they are useful

Comment: I did that, and it jumps right to `NSURLConnection.h`. I also tried to clean the project but didn't help.

Comment: Did you see `start` method in `NSURLConnection.h` file?

Comment: Yes, I can see `start`. I just reinstalled XCode and still failed. So I don't think it's cause by editing the header file

Comment: Can you log your full error message? Or you can capture screen. I need more information to resolve your problem